# Configuration setup for Glass fish server v4

Tags: glassfish

We are using java based web application. I have deployed application in glass-fish server.

After deployed the application url look like https://www.domain.net/applicationname/home.jsp but i don't want to enter the full url.

I need something like https://www.domain.net it will go to the application home page.

Can please example any one.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is to use Apache or Nginx as a load balancer or proxy in front of GlassFish. If you want to connect directly to GlassFish, you will need to set the context root of your application to `/`.

The most "portable" way to do this is in the web.xml, but you can do it at deploy time instead:

https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2007/08/30/glassfish-tip-have-your-application-be-the-root-application/